# Restrict Developer-Support User Role

Tags: magento-1, admin-panel, dashboard, access

We have a new overseas developer and we thought it would be better to take the safe side when giving access to the Dashboard, we created a separate account but need to limit access.
I attached an image for the Roles available and would appreciate to tell me which ones to restrict. The developer will apply security patches, updates, customization... But still we believe that giving full access would be risky.
I appreciate your help, image attached. 
[image]

Comment: please inform  devoloper will do what updates and customizations ? dont you give him files and database access ?

Comment: First...don't restrict your developer. If you don't trust him, find another one. Second. If he has access to the code and wants to cause harm he can and will. So, don't restrict your developer. Third...if you restrict his access to some sections and he blindly does some changes and screws up something on those sections? So, don't restrict your developer.

Comment: What I mean is that since he will have full access, he may be able to change the administrator password or billing access, or we won't be able to recover the Dashboard. The hosting provider said that it's not necessary to give Database or cPanel access from now.

Comment: @Marius I don't really know him yet and he won't be next to me. What we are doing is the wrong decision?

Comment: make him sign an NDA or something, but don't restrict him. If you don't trust him, don't hire him. Is simple as that.

Comment: @Ashraf create a new user and give him limited access sometime you have restrict the developer to his concern link. mean it's work related to order only access to that. i do work like this many times `it is good to restrict him`.

Comment: @Ashraf also better to take full back up of database if you give him only backend access.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I don't really know guys, this is confusing, you are suggesting to restrict him and Marius is saying No. But how would I Trust anyone online, I got him worknhire.com. I am risking this because I don't have any options, I will check NDA too. Qaisar can you please tell me from the image above what to Restrict and what to leave for him?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I am taking Full backup automatically every 2 days, thank you guys for those advices.

Comment: @Ashraf can you have tell what his work related too? as i mention order,product or etc. aslo if you are hiring from freelancer website you have to check his profile review at the end you have to trust him because he has access to your code..

Comment: @Ashraf if you know his name you can check whether he is certified devoloper or not [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/directory/) so you can confirm he is not bad in coding. Note :  i dont mean if he is not certified means he is not good devoloper.

Comment: @QaisarSatti He will be customizing Forms, adding pages, also applying security patches, installing extensions... In general everything. This is their profile when they applied http://worknhire.com/Contractor/Profile/133907 and here's their website http://www.thecrafter.in/ What do you think man?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I checked but I couldn't find him. I am not worried if he's bad or good in coding, I am just worried if they would be a threat since they will have full access.

Comment: @Ashraf after seeing the profile there is not `magento related  work` in his profile and also in his skill there are not `magento` mention. I will never go for hiring that developer. it is better find to find new other developer with better reviews and skill related to `magento`. on safe side backup your `database` and `your code` too.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I just checked man, he wrote to me in his proposal this "I am skilled in PHP, ASP.NET, Wordpress, Magento, Woocommerce, Codeigniter, Ruby with Rails and Android." I did a backup already. I'll get to know more those guys, but on both ways even if I chose someone else; I still don't know what to restrict from the Admin Panel

Comment: @Ashraf restrict your order,user and products. they are the main things.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Thank you! I will do that, mainly User access so he won't change the username and password!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your fear but, as said in the comments, the best solution is have someone you trust and will have full access.

What you can do is: create a new role for your developer and give access to everything, except:

- Dashboard
- Sales (all checkbox in this tree)
- System > Permissions > Roles (just this checkbox)
- System > Permissions > Users (just this checkbox)

This way, he will not be able to change users or password of your admin. Also, in a few exceptions, a developer don't need access to the dashboard and to the sales module.

You can do this to start a relationship with the developer, see if he will match your expectations and start trust him. With this access he will be able to create new pages and do some customization for you.

**Now, one important point is:** Access to the database, FTP and SSH is very necessary. He will need this, for example, to install new Magento security patches.

Comment: This is exactly what I am willing to do, I restricted them now plus what QaisarSatti mentioned. I created FTP access for him, but also he needs access for the cPanel?

Comment: Not for what you said, however, he may need access later to the database or some hosting information. Most of the hosting companies allow you to create a "developer" user in cPanel that will not have access to billing and financial account, that could be a temporary solution as well.